# Google graphs get rendered to small in pdf using Rotativa

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, rotativa

I have been struggling the past few days with getting Rotativa working the way I want it to. I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC core application but I'm really not experienced in it. I have a view in which google charts are being shown. I want that page to be able to be printed as an pdf. The view contains tables as well though, which need to be in the pdf as well (so I can't just add the charts as images to a .pdf file). Getting the charts to show up was already a challenge. But that I managed with the "--window-status ready" parameter and a little function in my view. But now all my graphs show up half the size that they usually are. And with everything I try one of two things happen. The browser just keeps on loading and never shows the pdf or the width of my graphs does not change at all. My code seems a bit to long of the view to post here so I used some site to share it: https://codepad.co/snippet/AjY4m7BZ .
If you need any more code, feel free to ask for it. I hope someone can help me. Because so far the internet hasn't been of much help.( I removed the tables from the code snippet btw to de-clutter the code a bit)

Comment: If anyone would stumble apon this. I solved it by setting my width of my graphs to a static number (1140 by 200). It certainly isn't an ideal solutiion but it works for a A4 pdf. It seems as if there is currently no real good way to do it otherwise.